# How would I code a core data attribute string to allow specific words to be edited in UI?

Tags: ios, core-data

The app is a question bank to help users write a essay. I require the option to customise stock questions (nouns+pronouns) to users specific essay question. For example

Stock question:

What [ variable ] trying to accomplish?

UI options to user:

- What   [ I am ]    trying to accomplish?
- What   [ is the writer ] trying to accomplish?
- What   [ is the journal ] trying to accomplish?
- What   [ userEntry ] trying to accomplish?

How would I code this? a UIPickerView or variable within the attribute

Comment: I think the question has nothing to do with Core data..Please confirm.

Comment: The What [ variable ] trying to accomplish?questions Core data model

Comment: The stock question What [ variable ] trying to accomplish? would mean at least 3 records in data model. Can I cut this down to 1 record by coding inside an entity-attribute [String] with UIPickerview/Variable or is the easiest solution to have every variation of question in data model?

Comment: It becomes messy for user input so should a search (for variable) and replace method on the attribute be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPickerView,In PickerView you can add this values ( I am ,is the writer ,is the journal ,userEntry ) .

And for better UX you can add UIPickerView to action sheet.It will looks good.